# Ruby - Limit on how often a command can be initiated

Tags: ruby, limit, sleep, repeat, spam

Anyone know how to apply a time limit to how often a command can be initiated in ruby? I know the sleep command exists and have been trying to apply it like so.
I want to prevent the repeated calling of the command, due to spam reasons. 
The app is a outgoing webhook in a slack channel where the user can call on the command: tip. To tip another user in the channel, I want to put a limit on a certain waiting period before that command can be used again.

```
def tip
  if sleep(5)
    tip @user amount
  else
    @result[:text:] = "Spam tipping is not allowed."
  end
end
```

Comment: `sleep(n)` returns `n` so `if sleep(5)` will always succeed and run `tip @user amount`. What exactly do you want the behavior of `tip` to be? Do you want it to really wait 5 seconds before doing anything? Or do you want it to just return doing nothing (maybe setting `@result[:text]`) unless a 5 second interval has transpired since the last time it did something?

Comment: Is this in a rails or other web application? If not, how is this command called?

Comment: @shelvacu i have updated my answer if it helps. User's have the ability to call on this command so i want stop the repeated spamming of it every 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Does the command "knows" who call it?

Comment: @Martin yes stored in the user _id variable. Which is different to the user variable used as the tipping target.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called "rate-limiting".

If you want to do it yourself, simply store a timestamp of when the command was last used for each user.

Then, every time the command is called, check the timestamp of when the user last called the command. If it is set (this is not the user's first time calling the command) and it was less than (for example) 5 seconds ago, then deny the request. Otherwise, let it go through and store a new timestamp.

There are also libraries to do this for you, see for example [rack-throttle](https://github.com/dryruby/rack-throttle).

Comment: Thank you very much my friend , worked like a treat :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a web app or something with user login and a database: just store a "last called" timestamp with the user & command, and check it.

If this is a command line, an easy way would be to store a small text file somewhere with that info (file with a single line with a time stamp of the last call).

Comment: I've updated my question which might give you a better insight to the problem, user's actually have the ability to call this command hence why i want to stop the repeated use of it every 1 second. If they do use it every one second, they are faced with the spam tipping error.